# Create deferred if no need to do action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I found myself write this many times and I wonder whether there is a shortcut for this code block:

```
function doSome() {
    var deferred = null;
    if (needToLoad) {
        deferred = load();
    } else {
        deferred = $.Deferred().resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Is this the only way to write this? Is there any jQuery shortcut for returning new deferred if no deferred created?

Comment: I don't think there is another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By employing a ternary, the function will simplify to a one-liner though there's no particular value in doing so other than reduction of code volume.

```
function doSome() {
    return (needToLoad) ? load().promise() : $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}
```

Comment: I know that.. I was looking for something that already exists in jQuery, but I understand now that there isn't. You can reduce the code more:
`return (needToLoad ? load() : $.Deferred().resolve()).promise();`

Comment: Agreed. I nearly posted that variant. You may be able to shift the `needToLoad` test into `load()` and call it unconditionally, but that would just shift the need to generate the resolved promise elsewhere.